# CSS - how to scroll a list in a div

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

How can I scroll only the list? I want the `.text` and the `.link-item` to be fixed and only scroll on the list inside the container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 74.4%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 233);
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.text {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(116, 124, 142);
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px 50px 0px 30px;
  color: rgb(116, 124, 142);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.link-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(87, 135, 253);
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">ACTION ITEMS</div>
  <div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="www.something.com" class="link-item">GO TO THE LAST ITEM</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see https://jsfiddle.net/htwL2rxc/ for a working fiddle.

Comment: Hey Liz. I was downvoted twice for answering the "GO TO THE LAST ITEM" part. Not sure if I deserve the downvotes. Also, I made the right way to use the scrolling part as well. Can you kindly clarify if I am wrong in this case? Thanks.

Comment: [This link may help](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:** Along with the CSS part, I have also answered the `GO TO THE LAST ITEM`. Not sure why this can be done *just* by using CSS alone, as `GO TO THE LAST ITEM` needs JavaScript. I am just concerned because my answer has been downvoted so added this note.

You cannot use just CSS for implementing the **`GO TO THE LAST ITEM`**. Add the `overflow` CSS and you need to use JavaScript to make it scroll to the bottom:

```
document.querySelector('.box').scrollTop = 1000;
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 74.4%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 233);
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.text {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(116, 124, 142);
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px 50px 0px 30px;
  color: rgb(116, 124, 142);
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.link-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(87, 135, 253);
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">ACTION ITEMS</div>
  <div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="www.something.com" class="link-item" onclick="document.querySelector('.box').scrollTop = 10000; return false;">GO TO THE LAST ITEM</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it with CSS.  Just see the two answers below.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Sorry did I understand the question wrong?

Comment: @Simon It says **`how to scroll a list in a div`** and **`GO TO THE LAST ITEM`**.

Comment: The CSS property overflow-y: scroll is meant to do exactly this, no need of JavaScript.

Comment: @NkoleEvans Clicking of `GO TO THE LAST ITEM` will need the use of JavaScript. Can you kindly correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @Soolie Oh sorry I did'nt see the go to the last item past. That DOES require JavaScript. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: @Simon Is the clarification clear? Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: Ok I see.  I have retracted my vote. Just as a point of interest will [this](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/how-do-i-link-to-different-sections-on-the-same-page-html-editor/) do the trick?  I'm no good with JavaScript so I am probably wrong.

Comment: @Simon That works, but the HTML element doesn't have an ID. Seems like a list. So no.

Comment: I have retracted my vote too. Misunderstood the question :)

Comment: No problem just a thought.

Comment: @Simon Martin's answer is kinda like your way... Check it out... Seems possible with an extra element.

Comment: @Martin ^^^ Acknowledge?

Comment: Yep it is I didn't see it.

Answer (score 4):

## Your .container Element:

Set the parent container (`.container`) size, and display type, and then set a `overflow-y:scroll;` property for the container. I also always like setting `max-height` too,  but I don't think it's essential.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 74.4%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(230,230,233);
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /****** NEW *****/
    max-height: 150px;   /****** NEW *****/
    overflow-y: scroll;  /****** NEW *****/
    overflow-x: hidden; /****** NEW *****/
 }
```

Be careful your `.container` div should **not** be an `inline` type display as manually setting the height will have no effect on inline elements (*by default `divs` are `block` type so you're ok*).

## Your .text Element:

You state:

> I want the .text and the .link-item to be fixed and only scroll on the list inside the container.

Because your text box is marked as `position: fixed` it will never scroll from its startpoint on the page. Remove your `position: fixed` or change this value to something else that suits your needs but allows this text box to scroll as required.

## Going to the bottom of the list:

While not stated specifically in the quesiton but [**outlined by Soolie in their answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399031/3536236) *(previously  downvoted)* there is also an anchor code stating:

```
 <a href="www.something.com" class="link-item">GO TO THE LAST ITEM</a>
```

This can be done easily (*at least, on the code snippet with Firefox it works a charm*) with an anchor link thus:

```
<a href="#bottom" class="link-item">GO TO THE LAST ITEM</a>
```

And a corresponding link on the final `<li>`:

```
<li id='bottom'>
```

Complete code:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 74.4%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(230,230,233);
    margin-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /****** NEW *****/
    max-height: 150px;   /****** NEW *****/
    overflow-y: scroll;  /****** NEW *****/
    overflow-x : hidden; /****** NEW *****/
 }
 
 .text {
    /** position: fixed **/
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(116,124,142);
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;
  }
  

.box {
   position: absolute;
   padding: 20px 50px 0px 30px;
   color: rgb(116,124,142);
   font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  .link-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(87,135,253);
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    right: 0;   /*** Right align the absolute position ***/
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">ACTION ITEMS</div>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li id='bottom'>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#bottom" class="link-item">GO TO THE LAST ITEM</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this can be done *just* by using CSS alone, as `GO TO THE LAST ITEM` needs JavaScript. I am just concerned coz my answer has been downvoted and just thought of asking the community's help.\

Comment: @Soolie while I appreciate your concern, I would find it strange to have a set of `<ul>` elements in a container that is smaller than them, and the want the default start to be at the bottom of the `ul` list. While I see your misunderstanding with the wording, I think that logic would dictate that if this *is* the intended desire, this structure of HTML (supplied in the question rather than sought in an answer) is the completely wrong way of even trying to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have updated my answer now to clarify things. Hope I don't deserve those downvotes (I am not accusing you, don't feel so). Just wanted to know if my answer is okay now?

Comment: This is good. But my approach is generic. To just scroll the div to the end. This is nice as well. You have my upvote! :D

Comment: @Soolie You raised a good point that many people (myself included) hadn't noticed as it hadn't been specifically asked. I'm pleased to see you're back on the + votes now! A good turn around `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the DIV that contains your list a fixed size then apply an overflow declaration. See below:

```
 .box {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 50px 0px 30px;
    color: rgb(116,124,142);
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;height: 120px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

give .box div overflow-y: auto; and preferred height size of div for scrolling.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```